# How to securely store external auth credentials in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, encryption

I am creating a mobile app that uses Google App Engine (python) for the backend. Users sign in with Twitter on the app, and the auth token and secret are passed to the backend (over https) so that the server can authenticate with Twitter and also periodically sync friends and followers in a background task. Because they are used by the background thread, I want to store the information in the datastore so they can be retrieved and used later.

Right now, during development and testing, I just put these in the datastore in plain text. But I'd like to add a little more security by storing it encrypted and decrypting it when its needed. Thank you for any help!

For general account passwords, I use

```
security.generate_password_hash(raw_password, length=12)
```

based on how `webapp2_extras` stores the passwords. But this approach wouldn't allow me to retrieve the data. Is there anything similar that allows for encryption and decryption?

Comment: While not the answer to the question as originally posed, I think the most secure solution is to rethink the problem and actually not rely on fetching that data from the datastore. I can kick off the twitter friend/follower sync whenever the user logs in again (with some extra conditions, to not do it on every login). The user will provide their twitter auth token and auth secret again during login, and I can pass that directly to the task that needs them.

Comment: Oh, and if I want to store their twitter auth credentials to reauthorize the user without confirming credentials with twitter, I can treat both auth_token and auth_secret as passwords in the datastore and check the user supplied values against them. (And reconfirm with Twitter if the newly supplied credentials don't match what is cached in the datastore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally for password storage you would use a unidirectional (One way) encryption technique so that no one can work out what the password is and then take the user supplied values and compare them to the stored values. This way you're never really storing the actual password and it's less likely to be stolen.

What you're looking for is a bidirectional encryption technique where by you provide the value and a key to create an encrypted value and can apply the key to the encrypted value to get the original.

You haven't stated which language you're using so I cannot provide a good example, however I suggest looking at techniques such as AES. Please keep in mind that if you choose an encryption technique with a short key it will be much easier to brute force. Any encryption that is bidirectional is at risk of easier brute force and once the key has been determined ALL passwords are at risk of being decrypted. Most languages have some form of support for AES and similar encryption techniques.

There are many techniques available, some much newer and more secure so do some research and see what you deem 'secure enough'.

Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

Comment: Thanks! I'll start looking into AES for this. I'll make sure to use different keys for this approach vs. the keys used to hash the passwords.

I'm using python by the way. By chance, would you happen to have any examples for python on google app engine?

Comment: I don't have a Python implementation of AES that is tested and confirmed working with App Engine however when I was looking at it I used a Python encryption library that made is very easy. I expect if you can import a similar library then you might be able to achieve the same results.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyways. Looks like GAE-python supports pycrypto, and the answer is likely somewhere in there.

Comment: pycrypto - That's the chap! Nice find, sorry I couldn't find it sooner. I moved over to Java App Engine. The encrypted string will contain some off characters and not all of them websafe. I suggest taking the encrypted string and turned that into Base64 which is very easily reversed. That way your encrypted string is nice and websafe while also technically being double encrypted. Example to follow found here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto